# Javascript's call stacks and execute order

Tags: javascript, stack, call

I'm learning call stack and I know it's in a 'first in last out' order, but why is JS code executed in a top to bottom order? Shouldn't the last item in the call stack (which is the first item to be popped out) be executed first?

Comment: which language is not executed top to bottom order when executing code? Regarding the stack you should look at basic data structures first.

Comment: This great tool will demonstrate how the call stack works: http://latentflip.com/loupe/?code=ZnVuY3Rpb24gYmFyKCkgewogICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coJ3dvcmxkJyk7Cn0KCmZ1bmN0aW9uIGZvbygpIHsKICAgIGNvbnNvbGUubG9nKCdoZWxsbycpOwogICAgYmFyKCk7CiAgICBjb25zb2xlLmxvZygnaG93IGFyZSB5b3U%2FJykKfQoKZm9vKCk7!!!PGJ1dHRvbj5DbGljayBtZSE8L2J1dHRvbj4%3D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without getting very technical, think of the following code,

```
function squared(value) {
  return value * value;
}

function cube(value) {
  return squared(value) * value;
}

cube(3);
```

Now, when the function `cube` is called, it's pretty obvious that, for the function `cube` to return it's computed value, it should compute the value of `squared` first and multiply the returned value.

This is the reason why inner functions are always executed first and then followed the outer functions because the outer functions might depend on the value returned by the inner functions.

Converting this to a stack, the call stack would look like

1. Initial empty Stack.

```
 |  |
  --
```

2. When function `cube` is called, it is inserted into stack.

```
|cube|
 ----
```

3. When function `cube` calls function `squared`, `squared` is inserted into the stack.

```
|squared|
| cube  |
 -------
```

4. `squared` does not call any more function, so function `squared` is popped from the stack, executed and the value is returned to `cube`

```
|cube| //squared()
 ----
```

5. Function `cube` is popped from the stack, executed and the value is returned to the invoker.

```
|   | // cube() * returned value from squared()
 ---
```

This is pretty much a very simple explanation of why a stack is used for function invocation and is pretty much used in all programming languages.

Comment: Happy to help.. :)